# C unknown-size structure

Tags: c

I am writing an app with the following dynamic config structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char apphash[41];
    char filenames_count;
    char * filename[64];
} config;
```

But this code is wrong, I can't figure out how to copy data from and to c->filename[0] properly; c is a pointer to config structure, allocated dynamically like

```
config * c = (config *) malloc( 42 + 64 * 2 ) // alloc for 2 filenames. can realloc() later.
```

It segfaults if I use something like `strcpy(c->filename[0],"file1.txt")`.

Can someone please help me with this?

Currently, I'm using direct address calculation, like

```
strcpy(
    (char*) 
    ((unsigned long) c + 42 /* apphash + filenames_count */ + 
    64 * 0 /* first item */ ),
    "file1.txt"
);
```

and it works of course.

You see, I'm more of assembly programmer than of C, but I'd like this code to be more human-readable. This code looks that bad because I'm newcomer in C.

---

Oh, I gave a bad description of the situation. Sorry for that :(
The real code looks like:

```
config * c = (config*) malloc( 42 + 64 * 2 );
// we may realloc() it later if we are going to add more filenames.

// failing example how I do copy one default filename
strcpy(c->filename[0],"file1.txt");

// working example (i386)
strcpy((char*)((unsigned long) c + 42 + 64 * 0),"file1.txt");
```

I am using fully static structure type because it is going to be loaded directly from a file next time. That's why I can't really use pointers inside the structure, I need real data to be placed there.
I do check all lengths, no BOFs in real code, I just omitted all that stuff here.

I still didn't find a good solution to this.

Thanks again and sorry for bad question information.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's part of the C standard headers, but look at `offsetof` to help automate your calculations.

Comment: Your `strcpy` seems to point to a possible misunderstanding on your part. `char *filename[64]` is an array of 64 `char *`s, not a pointer to an array of `char`s. Your `64 * 0` seems to indicate that you think it is the latter. As a hint, `cdecl` is a program that parses C declarations and describes them to you in plain English, and is incredibly helpful when you're not used to C. http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/

Comment: @unknown_c_newbie Even unregistered users can propose changes to their question, but you should really go ahead and just associate an OpenID(or password) with your account.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have many filenames since you have `filenames_count`. Try

```
config_obj.filename[0] = strdup("file1.txt")
```

Comment: and remember to `free()` the duplicated string(s)

Comment: +1 but `strdup` is a nonstandard (if easily implementable) function that may not be present on your compiler/platform (if your compiler/platform happens to suck badly).

Answer (score 3):

In your struct you're allocating an array of pointers to chars, not an array of chars. You must explicitely allocate also the targets of pointers, or at the very least, make the struct contain also the arrays of chars themselves:

```
char filename[64][MAX_PATH+1];
```

Replace MAX_PATH with the maximum length of any filename. Mind that this is not a very elegant solution, albeit a really simple one, because you're wasting lots of space.

Your direct address calculation is doing something different: it's placing the string directly in the space allocated for the pointers (and this is a Terribly Wrong Thing To Do™)

Comment: I believe it's intended to be an array of character pointers.  Another of the fields on the struct is `filenames_count`.

Comment: I know: the reason why the first strcpy fails is because most likely the OP hasn't actually allocated the memory for the strings, and the pointers in that array are uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

Right now `config` is a *type* that means the struct you have defined. You don't show us an identifier referring to an actual variable of type `config`.

So, first thing we need an instance of type `config`. You will either do

```
config c;
... c.filename ...
```

note the structure access operator is a `.`, or you will do something like

```
config *p = malloc(config)
/* error checking */
...c->filename ...
```

where `->` is the pointer-dereference-and-access operator. The first form is preferred unless you hve a reason to want dynamic allocation (which, alas, happens a lot in c).

Then you have to figure out just what you want `filename` to be. As it is you have allocated space for 64 character pointers which *don't* point at allocated memory (except by purest acident, and then not at the memory you mean). You probably wanted{*} `char filename[64]` (a single filename allowed to be up to 63 characters long (to leave room for the null termination)) in which case you would use

```
strcpy(c.filename,"file1.txt");
/* or */
strcpy(p->filename,"file1.txt");
```

depending on how you allocated the structure in the first place.

If you really wanted a *list* of filenames, then you may want `char *filenames[64]`, but you will have to allocate a buffer for each name before you can use it

```
c.filenames[0] = malloc(sizeOfString);
/* error checking */
strcpy(c.filenames[0],...
```

or as another poster suggested

```
c.filenames[o] = strdup(...
```

The first form may be better if you are building your filenames from multiple pieces and can project the total length from the get go.

---

{*} Later you may want to scrap this fixed length buffer, but leave that for now.

Comment: This would have been better as a comment on the question, rather than as an answer.

Comment: @Inuyasha: Iterative improvement.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently failing because you aren't allocating memory for the filenames. Either use strdup or malloc+strcpy (I'd use strdup).

Your filename field is an array of pointers to zero terminated string. You need to allocate the memory for the string and copy the string to that memory. You save the address of the new string in one of the pointers, e.g. filename[0].

The direct memory address code doesn't work. It just doesn't crash, yet! That code just overwrites the array of pointers. Don't ever write code like that. Never ever ever!! Writing code like that is morally equivalent to eating baby unicorns.